# Hot water radiator valve leaks

Tags: leak, valve, radiator

The attached picture shows the valve on a hot water radiator that leaks and the arrow points to where it leaks. It drips about one drop a minute.

It feels like a quarter turn on that nut might fix the leak, but is that dangerous? Would I be risking making the leak worse?

Any other suggestions for stopping the leak?

[image]

Comment: You need to replace or fix the valve. On old work, yes, you risk snapping/bending something stuck/corroded that would make things MUCH worse. It's very dangerous if the heat is on. That being said, I would _try_ reworking the nut (ex silicone tape)  and call a plumber if it was at all difficult to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tighten the nut slightly to stop the drip. If it is frozen do not force it since the nut could crack and cause a worse problem as @dandavis  commented. If you can back off the nut you could repack the valvr but I would call a plumber or HVAC person to do it unless you have experience repacking valves.